# How to use Facebook Photos in an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, xml, facebook, photos

I have a client who wants to use their Facebook photos in an iPhone app. We want to embed their account into the app so that when people download the app, they see the client's Facebook photos. The user should not need to login or connect to Facebook.

This is different than the standard "connect to facebook so we can access you data" - we have no need to access the users data.

Do I need to create a Facebook App, connect the client's Facebook account to the Facebook app, then use that to get the photo data ?

---

Ok, here is what I found

My business page is http://www.facebook.com/pages/Feltpad-Web-Mobile/128861547181352

That number at the end (`128861547181352`) is the business' "Facebook Graph ID"

Then use the Business Graph ID and go to http://graph.facebook.com/128861547181352/albums and you will see a list of all of the Photo Albums associated with the business' page. There is only one album, so that is all the info you get. The first valuable line on that page says `"id": "133208113413362"` - this is the Facebook Graph ID for the album.

Then use the Album's Graph ID and go to http://graph.facebook.com/133208113413362/photos - this will give you a JSON file with all the data you need for all the photos in the album.

You can also use `?limit=25` and `?offset=50` or both `?limit=25&offset=50` to page through the results.

Comment: Good stuff. But I guess you can't see any Facebook user's public album the same way.

Comment: Hmm... maybe this only works for 'pages' and not for user profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be easy. Facebook gives a public URL for albums that are **public** to be viewed by the Internet without necessity of logging in. You can see this URL al the bottom of the album page that you may want to share.

It looks like this:

> Share this album with anyone by sending them this public link:
>   http://www.facebook.com/album.php?aid=[ALBUM_ID]&id=[USER_ID]&l=[SOME_PARAM]

(quoted from a public album)

you can easily leach data and extract images from there.

---

However it is more sane to create a Facebook app (takes hardy a minute) and use Facebook graph-API to make REST calls to retrieve all the data about albums and photos within them in well formatted JSON that will be far easier to handle the HTML. Once you have Facebook App in place, you may use it to fetch all the FB data but it violates both of your requirements (1)Not using Facebook app, and (2) user don't have to sign-in.

But it may worth looking at

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album

---

Well, there is some trick. If you go to the API page(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api). Copy the URL given for Coca-Cola album (https://graph.facebook.com/99394368305) and make a request with `photos` REST command like https://graph.facebook.com/99394368305/photos you can access all the details of all the photos in the album in JSON format. I could not get it work for my personal public album though.

Comment: Well that is an option, but I am hoping for an XML or JSON output where I can get the thumbnails, fullsize images, etc. Plus if they change the code on the those photo pages, the app would break.

Comment: @Chris exactly on the point. It's weird that graph API does not give JSON object of _public_ albums. Or I am missing something. It should ideally be available same as public profiles are http://graph.facebook.com/4 Lets dig a bit more in FB docs.

Comment: @Chris great! I will be interest in knowing. BTW, updated the answer.