# How to get data(json array) of facebook public photo by using photo url?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to get details of public photo of any user's facebook account.

here is my image url : http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=346729048691589&set=a.346719012025926.83282.100000634900314&type=1&l=f48e02a2e3&permPage=1

and i want details of this photo so i have generated url like : http://graph.facebook.com/346729048691589/albums but getting data as blank array. and also in my album all the photos are public.

I read this url : [How to use Facebook Photos in an iPhone App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909171/how-to-use-facebook-photos-in-an-iphone-app) and  example getting the result and i want the same result also but some how i am not getting it.

And i read that we don't require access token if we want to use any public details of facebook but here i am not getting the result.

So Can any one help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How to get data(json array) of facebook public photo by using photo url?

What I did was to take the fbid from the querystring of your image url in your question.  Then I went to the graph API explorer tool and brought it up.  See link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=346729048691589

When I did that it returned:

```
{
  "id": "346729048691589",
  "from": {
    "name": "Development SandBox",
    "id": "100000634900314"
  },
  "picture": "http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/421606_346729048691589_216224001_s.jpg",
  "source": "http://sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc7/421606_346729048691589_216224001_n.jpg",
  "height": 469,
  "width": 700,
  "images": [
    {
      "width": 700,
      "height": 469,
      "source": "http://sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc7/s720x720/421606_346729048691589_216224001_n.jpg"
    },
    {
      "width": 180,
      "height": 120,
      "source": "http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/421606_346729048691589_216224001_a.jpg"
    },
    {
      "width": 130,
      "height": 87,
      "source": "http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/421606_346729048691589_216224001_s.jpg"
    },
    {
      "width": 75,
      "height": 50,
      "source": "http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/421606_346729048691589_216224001_t.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=346729048691589&set=a.346719012025926.83282.100000634900314&type=1",
  "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
  "created_time": "2012-02-10T11:14:42+0000",
  "position": 2,
  "updated_time": "2012-02-10T11:14:43+0000",
  "type": "photo"
}
```